# Form with Image Div or Container

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, file-upload

I'm there. I'm wondering how to make a form that have a container or box somewhere upper left.

The form has fille upload and the moment that the user chosen a photo in the file upload box (without submitting) the photo will appear on that photo container/box.

Can you give me guide? Thanks

Comment: of course no one will programm this for you, just google and you will find a lot tutorials. here you can ask if someone explain you specific questions because you dont understand some. not if someone can write you a guide or something like this.

Comment: [Refer this tutorial](http://www.freakycoders.com/web/uploading_file_using_php_and_jquery), If face any problem in your implementation, ask your doubts here..

Comment: guess you are looking for some like [mini ajax uploader](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is possible.You'll need to use **[`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)** API(works in IE 9+) for that.

and Here is the demo for the same:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Reader Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
#err{
background:#faa;
color:#fff;
border:2px solid #f00;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
}
#preview{
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:2px solid #444;
background:#eee;
text-align:center;
font-size:24px;
color:cyan;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fileStarter(x){
var file = x.files[0];
var size=file.size;
size=size/(1024*1024);
if(size<3.5){
var imageType = /image.*/;
var fileDisplayArea=document.getElementById("preview");
if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("err").style["display"]="none"; 
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = reader.result;
    img.setAttribute("title","Preview is Shown here");
    img.setAttribute("width","100%");
    img.setAttribute("height","100%");
     fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
} else {
document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="Invalid File Type! Allowed files are .bmp, .gif, .jpg and .png only";
    document.getElementById("err").style.display="block"; 

}
}
else {
document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="File is too large ! At max 3.5Mb is allowed!";
    document.getElementById("err").style.display="block"; 

}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br /><center>
<h3 style='border-bottom:2px dashed #ff9933'> Please Do Upload Your Photo </h3>
<br />Currently Your Pic is:<br /><div id="preview" class="preview">

Preview Of Your Photo

</div>
<form action="UploadScript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" Onsubmit="return upsub(this,event);">
<input type='file' id='profpic' name="profpic" onchange='fileStarter(this);'>
<br /><br />
<div class="invalid" id="err" style="display:none;"></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload My Pic">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the working: 

## `Fiddle`.

In that Demo it'll allow you to choose file from you device and as soon as you choose/select one image then it'll show its preview in the preview box before submitting it to server as you asked in your question.

It will also do validation on size of file and file type if required.

To make it available for multiple file I'll suggest you to use `<input type="file">` with `multiple` attribute first of all and then dynamically append `<div id='preview'>` to body for each file and show it's 
preview in that appended `<div>` using `for` or `while` loop for every file using `files.length` property in that.

Hope it'll help you. Cheers :)!!

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I need. Thanks for the guide :) Image Preview that is you call it, Sorry I'm new to that thing. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: That Okay! I'm glad that I could help you. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this tutorial also.

http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload-form-using-jquery/